# How can I make objects with functions? (Turning a string into a object name)

Tags: python-3.x

I've just started learning Python recently and the first project I'm making is a text based adventure game however I've run into a problem. I need a function that makes more objects using the class Goblin that are named after a string.

```
def spawn(name):
    title = name
    exec("{0} = {1}".format('title', Goblin))
    return title, 'spawn'
```

Essentially, another function calls this function to create another Goblin (a class) using the input name(a string) as the name of the new Goblin.

What I don't under stand though is that when I run the code(using "bill" as the argument), it gives me this error.

```
bill = <class '__main__.Goblin'>
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Shouldn't my function be equivalent to:

```
bill = Goblin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
exec("{0} = {1}".format('title', Goblin))
```

`format` method converts `Goblin` class by calling default `__str__` method which yields `<class '__main__.Goblin'>`

Do this instead:

```
exec("{0} = {1}".format('title', 'Goblin'))
```

Wait! don't to this, just do:

```
title = Goblin
```

as it's strictly equivalent (without any security issues :)).

But that will just alias `Goblin` class to `title`. No real interest to all this after all (unless you want to create an instance?: `title = Goblin()`)

With your comment: "I want a Goblin that is named after the string which title represents" I get it: you need

```
exec("{0} = {1}".format(title, 'Goblin()'))
```

(no quotes for the first arg so the name you're passing is used, and `()` on the second to create an instance)

Again: this is really a clumsy way of doing it. What if you want to iterate through *all* your goblins?

It would be much better to create a dictionary:

```
goblins_dict = dict()
goblins_dict["my_goblin"] = Goblin()
goblins_dict["my_goblin_2"] = Goblin()
```

and so on...

Comment: Wouldn't using title = Goblin() just create a Goblin called title?

Comment: I want a Goblin that is named after the string which title represents.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The dictionary seems like the best solution.